# How do I create a form with a json via javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a Json file. and I want to produce a form with them via javascript . I want to generate inputbox if type was 128 and want to generate it dynamically. the form that i expect to generate i s somthing like this :

```
<form action="">
  name:<br>
  <input type="text" class="input1" id="input1" data-value="0">
 <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is my Javascript code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < schema.length; i++) {
    var type=schema[i].type;
    if(type==128){ 

        var titleinput=schema[i].queestion
        var divtitle=document.getElementById('input');
        divtitle.innerHTML=titleinput;


        var string = "<input ";
        for (var y=0;y<schema[i].attrs.length;y++){
            string += schema[i].attrs[y].attr.name+'="'+schema[i].attrs[y].attr.value+'" '
        }
    }
        string+=">";
        var y=document.getElementById('addinput'); 
        y.innerHTML=string;

    }
```

and here is my Json file :

```
{
    "queestion":"نام" ,
    "type":"128",
    "attrs":[
        {"attr":{
            "name":"class",
            "value":"input1"
        }},
        {"attr":{
            "name":"id",
            "value":"input1"
        }},
        {"attr":{
            "name":"data-value",
            "value":"0"
        }}
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON data:

{
    "employees": [
        {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Anna",
            "lastName": "Smith"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Peter",
            "lastName": "Jones"
        }
    ]
}

need to push each column (firstName, lastName) to the '{}' brackets
var viewData = { 
    employees : [] 
};

var rowNum = -1; 
function onGeneratedRow(columnsResult)
{
    var jsonData = {};
    columnsResult.forEach(function(column) 
    {
        var columnName = column.metadata.colName;
        jsonData[columnName] = column.value;
    });
    viewData.employees.push(jsonData);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var schema = [{
    "queestion":"name" ,
    "type":"128",
    "attrs":[
        {"attr":{
            "name":"class",
            "value":"input1"
        }},
        {"attr":{
            "name":"id",
            "value":"input1"
        }},
        {"attr":{
            "name":"data-value",
            "value":"0"
        }}
    ]

},{
    "queestion":"gender" ,

    "type":"137",
    "attrs":[
        {"attr":{
            "name":"class",
            "value":"input1"
        }},
        {"attr":{
            "name":"id",
            "value":"input1"
        }},
        {"attr":{
            "name":"data-value",
            "value":"0"
        }}
    ],
    "values":[
        {"value":{
            "title":"famale",
            "value":"0"
        }},
        {"value":{
            "title":"male",
            "value":"1"
        }}
    ]
}]

for (var i = 0; i < schema.length; i++) {
 var type=schema[i].type;
 if(type==128){ 
  var titleinput=schema[i].queestion; 
  var divtitle=document.getElementById('input'); 
 divtitle.innerHTML=titleinput + " : "; 
 var string = "<input "; 
 for (var y=0;y<schema[i].attrs.length;y++){ 
  string += schema[i].attrs[y].attr.name+'="'+schema[i].attrs[y].attr.value+'" ' 
 } 
 string+=">"; 
 console.log(string) 
 var y=document.getElementById('addinput'); 
 y.innerHTML=string; 
}
if(type==137){
var titleinput=schema[i].queestion; 
  var divtitle=document.getElementById('select'); 
 divtitle.innerHTML=titleinput + " : "; 
 var str = "<select><option>gender</option>";
 for (var j = 0; j < schema[i].values.length; j++) {
  str +="<option value='"+schema[i].values[j].value.value+"'>"+schema[i].values[j].value.title+"</option>"
 }
 str +='</select>'
 var x=document.getElementById('option'); x.innerHTML=str;
}
}
```

```css
.container{
  display : flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="input"></div><div id="addinput"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="select"></div><div id="option"></div>
</div>
```

`I suppose this should help you @Hadis,` https://jsfiddle.net/vikramgopali/wr7b6uzx/

Comment: Instead of pointing to a Fiddle, show your code here. Your answer should contain the code to the solution, not just links.

Comment: Oh sorry will do it. Sorry for the inconvenience caused to you. You happy now?@SaschaM78

Answer (score 0):

Use **for (.. in ..)** loop to parse your JSON data and make the form dynamically.

if the data in **json_data** variable. Then,

```
for (x in json_data){
console.log(x) //this will print the key 
console.log(json_data[x]) //this will print the corresponding value
}
```

In this way you can create dynamic forms using any json data in javascript.
I think this would helps you.